# Can I use SearchKit to display a specific Contact Tag on a public directory?

Tags: tags, searchkit, directory

I am building a membership directory and want to display information on each member that is contained in the form of Contact Tags. I can obviously display the full list of Tags, but we use some for back office purposes.
I am using SearchKit to build the dataset for the directory, as the requirements go beyond the capabilities of other Civi searches.
So for instance, I would like to display (on a public directory / form) the Tag "Founding Contributor" (which identifies a category of donor) whilst excluding other Tags associated with that Contact.
I have Tags grouped in Tag Sets, which helpfully distinguish "back office" Tags from others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to if you add 'Contact Tags' as a required or optional entity and then limit to the specific tag you want to include.

[image: Basic SearchKit]

Comment: Thank you so much Rebecca - problem solved!

Comment: I have a supplementary question. I want to display more than one Contact Tag in the Directory. How can this be achieved with Searchkit? I guess it might be difficult to filter Tags in a record to show only those I wish to publish within the one Contact.Tag column, and I can't see how I could add a line to the query to show a different Tag in a separate column of the table.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that I can specify a second Contact.Tag as an optional entity to show a second Tag in a separate Column...